# Plotting log of relative hazard by groups in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
dd <- datadist(EB); options(datadist='dd')

f <- cph(Surv(time, event) ~ CV, data=EB)

ggplot(Predict(f))+ ylab ("Log relative hazard for primary outcome")+ xlab("Continuous value")+
  ggtitle("Association between continuous value and primary endpoint")
```

This is the R code I used to create this association graph between CV (continuous value) and the primary endpoint. However, I would like to have the same graph with curves for each region.

[image]

I did this code :

```
ggplot(Predict(f, CV, Region))
```

And I obtain this graph below. I don't like it very much, I would like it to be identical to the one above but with lines for the different regions. I don't really understand those interval bands either. Can you help me to make it correct? I would like the **log relative hazard by region** .

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Programming questions should be posted to stackoverflow.com or for the R `rms` package to datamethods.org/rms.  To answer your question you can feed the result of `Predict` into any `ggplot2` code you like to achieve faceting with `facet_wrap`.  The help file for `ggplot.Predict` also shows how to do this directly with `ggplot(Predict(...), ~ region)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, however I would like to have in the same plot, the estimated curves of the log reative hazard by region (with different colour for each region). With facet_wrap, it gives me a panel for each category

Comment: If I do: ggplot(Predict(f), groups =  "Region"), it gives to me just the line for the first region

Comment: Then just run a series of completely separate plots.  For each one you can use `Predict(fit, CV, region='whatever region')`.